# How to update payment request when the amount changes in stripe using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

i have this useEffect and i am using stripe `PaymentRequestButtonElement` for `ApplePay` and `Google Pay`  . Everything is working fine , Now the problem i am facing is when the user updates the item quantity the `orderTotal` changes - But the stripe still shows same old amount when the user clicks on button. How to update the payment request with updated amount.

```
`useEffect(() => {
    async function createPaymentRequest() {
      if (!stripe || !elements) return;
      const PaymentRequestRes = stripe.paymentRequest({
        country: "IND",
        currency: "inr",
        total: {
          label: "Total",
          amount: orderTotal * 100,
        },
        requestPayerName: true,
        // disableWallets: ["link", "browserCard"],
      });

      const result = await PaymentRequestRes.canMakePayment();
      if (result) setPaymentRequest(PaymentRequestRes);

      PaymentRequestRes.on("paymentmethod", async (event) => {
        const createStripePaymentIntent = await stripeCreatePaymentMethod();
        if (
          createStripePaymentIntent?.success === 1 &&
          createStripePaymentIntent?.gatewayData?.data?.client_secret &&
          createStripePaymentIntent?.gatewayData?.isVerified === false
        ) {
          event.complete("success");
          const confirmpayload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
            createStripePaymentIntent?.gatewayData?.data?.client_secret,
            {
              payment_method: event.paymentMethod.id,
            },
            { handleActions: false }
          );
          if (
            confirmpayload?.paymentIntent?.status === "succeeded" 
          ) {
            verifyStripePaymentIntent(confirmpayload?.paymentIntent?.id);
          }
          //confirm payment failed
          else {
            console.log("error")
          }
        } else {
         console.log("error")
          event.complete("fail");
          return;
        }
      });
    }
    createPaymentRequest();

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [stripe, elements, orderTotal, selectedStore?._id]);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paymentRequest.update` to change the amount shown. See https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_request/update - Like what the docs mention, to update the PaymentRequest right before the payment interface is initiated, call `paymentRequest.update` in your click event handler.

This worked for me, although I'm not entirely certain if this is the best way to go about it in React

```
...
const updatePaymentRequestInstance = async (event) => {
      paymentRequest.update({
        total: {
          label: 'Demo total',
          amount: orderTotal * 100,
        }
      });
    }
...
<PaymentRequestButtonElement 
options={{paymentRequest}} 
onClick={updatePaymentRequestInstance} />
...);
```

Also, you should be reusing the same PaymentRequest Instance and not recreating it every time the `orderTotal` and `selectedStore?._id` changes.

Comment: @alex- How to use it here in my example