# stripe get updated amount when click on Payment Request Button

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

i am using stripe paymentReuestButton for googlePay and wallet , when the amount changes i update the request.  i have two useEffects one for listening creating payment request and one for updating request - The problem i am facing is when i click on payment Request Button , I have add validation on amount, but here i am getting old amount not the updated one.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  PaymentRequestButtonElement,
  useStripe,
  useElements,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { t } from "i18next";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { stripeCreatePaymentMethod, verifyStripePaymentIntent } from "./utils";
import C from "Constants";
const WalletPay = () => {
  const { orderGrossAmount } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  

  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [paymentRequest, setPaymentRequest] = useState(null);
  let fallBackMessage = t("Bank declined payment, please try again");

  const requestObj = {
    country: "IN",
    currency: "inr",
    total: {
      label: "Total",
      amount: Math.round(orderGrossAmount * 100),
    },
    requestPayerName: true,
    // disableWallets: ["link", "browserCard"],
  };

  // updating the request
  useEffect(() => {    
    if (paymentRequest &&orderGrossAmount) {
      if (paymentRequest.isShowing()) {
         setLoading(true);
        return;
      } else setLoading(false);
      paymentRequest.update({
        total: {
          label: "Total",
          amount: Math.round(orderGrossAmount * 100),
        },
      });
    }
  }, [paymentRequest, orderGrossAmount]);

 

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      async function createPaymentRequest() {
        if (!stripe || !elements) return;

        const PaymentRequestRes = stripe.paymentRequest(requestObj);
        const result = await PaymentRequestRes.canMakePayment();
        if (result) setPaymentRequest(PaymentRequestRes);

        const button = elements.getElement(PaymentRequestButtonElement);

        PaymentRequestRes.on("cancel", () => {
          const updatedAmount = Math.round(orderGrossAmount * 100);
          console.log("Updated Amount:", updatedAmount);
          window.location.reload(false);
        });

        button?.on("click", async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log({ preventDefault: orderGrossAmount });
          // const pl =
        });

        PaymentRequestRes.on("paymentmethod", async (event) => {
          const createStripePaymentIntent = await stripeCreatePaymentMethod(
            orderGrossAmount);
          if (
            createStripePaymentIntent
          ) {
            event.complete("success");
            const confirmpayload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
              createStripePaymentIntent?.gatewayData?.data?.client_secret,
              {
                payment_method: event.paymentMethod.id,
              },
              { handleActions: false }
            );
            if (
              confirmpayload?.paymentIntent?.status === "succeeded" 
            ) {
              verifyStripePaymentIntent(
                confirmpayload?.paymentIntent?.id,
                
              );
            }
            //confirm payment failed
            else
              console.log("error")
          } else {
             console.log("error")
            event.complete("fail");
            return;
          }
        });
      }
      createPaymentRequest();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error({ error });
       console.log("error")
    }

    

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [stripe, elements]);


  if (loading)
    return<h4>Processing Payment</h4>
  else return paymentRequest &&
    <PaymentRequestButtonElement options={{ paymentRequest }} />
  
  
};

export default WalletPay;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update payment request when the amount changes in stripe using reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77064385/how-to-update-payment-request-when-the-amount-changes-in-stripe-using-reactjs)